# Solving equations with dozens of ceil and floor functions efficiently?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am tackling a problem which uses lots of equations in the form of:

$$
q_i(x) = c_i(x) +
 \sum_{j=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{q_i(x)}{P_j} \right\rfloor C_j
$$

where $q_i(x)$ is the only unknown, $c_i$, $C_j$, $P_j$ are always positive. $C_j < P_j$ for all $j$

1. How is this type of problems efficently solved especially when the number of iterations $N$ is between 20 - 100?

What I was doing is $q_i(x) - c_i(x)$ must be equal to the summation of integers. So i was doing an exhaustive search for $q_i(x)$ which satisfies both ends of the equation. Clearly this is computationally exhaustive even if I do the search on a parallel computer..

1. What if $c_i(x)$ is a floating point number, this will even make the problem even more difficult to find a real $q_i(x)$?

Thanks

Comment: What can you say about the $C_j$s? Are they always positive, for instance?

Comment: $c_i,\ C_j\ and\ P_j$ are always positive. I will assume for now they are integers but later on they are changed to be real numbers.

Comment: j is just and index, $1,\ 2 ...\ N$

Comment: No, it is q_i, it is the same term on the left side

Comment: If you ignore for a moment the floor operation, the equation becomes $q_i(x)=c_i(x)+q_i(x)\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{C_j}{P_j}$, which is straightforward. Depending on you constants, the solution of the linearized equation can be a good approximation. By the way, you are computing the sum of a number of regular staircase functions, giving an irregular staircase function, and intersect it with a straight line. The solution not be unique.

Comment: Any proof to what you just suggested?

Comment: If $q$ is large compared to $C_j$ and $P_j$, the staircases are approximated by straight lines.

Comment: It won't work in my case. Q is not large.

Comment: The solution is probably not unique.

Comment: I know that. I am in interested in knowing the first few solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposal:

[For the sake of brevity the unknown $q_i(x)$ is denoted $Q$ and $c_i(x)$, $C$.] All constants can be real.

The right hand side is a sum of regular staircase functions, with the steps having width $P_j$ and height $C_j$. You can construct the resulting sum for increasing $Q$, from $Q=0$, by finding all discontinuities. The discontinuities occur at integer multiples of the widths, i.e. $k_jP_j$.

[image]

Maintain a vector with components $(k_j+1)P_j$, and a corresponding sum $S=C+\sum k_jC_j$. Initialize all $k_j=0$ and $S=C$. Now take the smallest of the $(k_j+1)P_j$ and increment $k_j$: $k_jP_j$ is increased by $P_j$, and $S$ by $C_j$.

Doing this repeatedly, you will enumerate all discontinuities, by increasing order. Between two successive discontinuities, let at $Q'$ and $Q''$, the sum is constant and equals the current S. You have a solution $Q=S$ every time that $Q'\le S\le Q''$.

For efficient implementation, the list of future discontinuities $(k_j+1)P_j$ is better organized as a priority queue.

Assuming that the first solution is found after the $M^{th}$ discontinuity, the running time will be $O(M\log N)$.

UPDATE:

Given that $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$, we have this bracketing for $S$:
$$C+Q\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{C_j}{P_j}-\sum_{j=1}^NC_j<S=C+\sum_{j=1}^N\lfloor\frac Q{P_j}\rfloor C_j\le C+Q\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{C_j}{P_j}.$$

By equating the bounds (magenta and black lines) to $Q$ (green), you get a good estimate of the range where solutions can be found. (If you start from a nonzero $Q$, you can initialize $k_j=\lfloor\frac Q{P_j}\rfloor$.)

Comment: It is clear from your argument and plot that we have to deal with a finite set of horizontal line sections, which we can of course determine and test for intersection with the diagonal of the identity. I looks like you did that and gave a criterion for intersection, albeit I did not understand it fully yet.

Comment: Yes, that's it. In addition, I provided an estimate of the search interval, by bracketing, as well as an efficient algorithm to enumerate the sections.

Comment: Is the the sum of two constant/increasing stair case functions a similar curve, just with different spacings - that seems one of the important recognitions here. Plus the idea to trace that resulting sum staircase of all $N$ individual staircase functions.

Comment: Yves, thanks so much for your solution it is extremely practical to program. I will attempt to use it in my simulations now. If all goes fine, i will mark it s the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

It is confusing to write $q_i(x)$ and $c_i(x)$ when they are really just numbers. I suppose this problem is part of a larger problem where you're trying to solve many such equations. Anyhow, let me rewrite your equation as
$$Q = C + \sum_{j = 1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{Q}{P_j} \right\rfloor C_j$$
where

- $Q$ is the unknown number (you wrote $q_i(x)$)
- $C$ is a positive number (you wrote $c(x)$)
- $P_j$'s and $C_j$'s are positive numbers and $C_j < P_j$ for all $j$.

Define the function $f$ to be
$$f(x) = C + \sum_{j = 1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{x}{P_j} \right\rfloor C_j.$$
We are trying to solve
$$Q = f(Q)$$
which is a [fixed point equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)). The function $f$ is monotonically increasing. To get some feel for it, let's consider the example $C = 11$, $N = 10$, $P_j = 10 j + 1$ and $C_j = 2 j$. We draw the graph of $y = f(x)$ and $y = x$, and observe where they intersect (magenta is $f$):

[image: graph of f]

As you see, there are several solutions. There is a well-known method for finding fixed points of functions:

1. Start with an arbitrary approximation, say $X_0 = 0$
2. Define $X_{k+1} = f(X_k)$
3. Keep computing $X_0$, $X_1$, $X_2$, ... until you get $X_{k+1} = X_k$, or at least $|X_{k+1} - X_k| < \epsilon$ for an acceptably small $\epsilon$.

There is no guarantee the process will actually find a fixed point, but at least in our case it does, we get: $X_0 = 0$, $X_1 = 11$, $X_2 = 13$, $X_3 = 13$, so $X = 13$ is a solution. Depending on what your $P_j$ and $C_j$ look like this method may work well.

Comment: Upvote for dropping the dependencies on $x$.

Comment: Yeah, but @YvesDaoust solution takes the next step and actually finishes off the problem. Upvote that one too :-)

Comment: I did of course.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps for your set of parameters, but it is an alternative view on the problem.

This system can be written as:
$$
\begin{align}
q_i(x) &= c_i(x) +
 \sum_{j=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{q_i(x)}{P_j} \right\rfloor C_j \\
&= c_i(x) +
 \sum_{j=1}^N \left( \frac{q_i(x)}{P_j} -f_j \right) C_j \\
&= c_i(x) +
q_i(x) \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{C_j}{P_j} -
\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{C_j}{P_j} f_j 
\end{align}
$$
with 
$$
f_j:f_j(q_i(x)) = \mbox{frac}\left(\frac{q_i(x)}{P_j}\right) \in [0, 1)
$$

And this gives another fixed point equation
$$
q_i(x) = \frac{c_i(x)-r f(q_i(x))}{1 - s(r)} =: \Phi(q_i(x)) \quad (*)
$$
(with $r_j = C_j / P_j >0$ and $s(r) = \sum_{i=1}^N r_j> 0$) if $s(r) \ne 1$.
For $s(r) < 1$ we get
$$
q_i(x) \in 
\left( \frac{c_i(x)}{1-s(r)}-\frac{s(r)}{1-s(r)},
 \frac{c_i(x)}{1-s(r)} \right]
$$
and for $s(r) > 1$ we get
$$
q_i(x) \in \left[ -\frac{c_i(x)}{s(r)-1},
 -\frac{c_i(x)}{s(r)-1} + \frac{s(r)}{s(r)-1}\right)
$$

For $s(r) = 1$ one has to solve
$$
r f(q_i(x)) = c_i(x)
$$

Comment: Thanks mvw. Your solution is quite a creative way to look at the problem but Yves Daoust approach is more practical and easy to program.

Comment: I will drop it. I think Yves got it nailed. Maybe I try a simpler explanation than his.